# Is there an alarm clock event log?

Tags: alarm

Occasionally I wake up and find out that I've missed an alarm. I'm considering using a different program that is more likely to wake me, for example [Math Alarm Clock](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-av-mac-jiiw.aspx). However before torturing myself with mathematical problems every morning I would first like to find out why I missed the alarm to see if there is an easier solution to the problem.

- Did I try to hit the snooze button but accidentally turned it off?
- Did I not hear it even though it rang 5 times?
- Did I set it for the wrong time and it didn't ring at all?
- etc...

In order to help investigate what the problem was I'd like to see a list of alarm related events. Is there any log where I can see all (or recent) alarm clock events, including changing alarms, alarms ringing and being turned off?

I use the currently use the default alarm clock on the HTC Desire, but if the logging feature is only available in another alarm clock application I would consider switching.

Comment: Do you use a task killer? Don't kill the "Clock" application, as the Alarm wouldn't ring otherwise. Better yet, don't use a task killer, Android manages your applications intelligently, and will kill unused applications if another applications needs the memory.

Answer (score 5):

The only place that I can think of off the top of my head would be the logcat logs.  There's an app on the market called aLogcat that will show you the full system logs, or you can use a terminal emulator and just run the command 'logcat' to get the scrolling log output. There's also DDMS, available through the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), that will show you the system logs from your phone on the computer as well.

Honestly, I'm not sure if the Alarm is something that is reported to the logcat logs or not, but it'd definitely be worth checking.

Comment: I tried installing aLogcat, and while it seems a useful program for debugging errors I don't think it will work for this. I tried filtering on "alarm" and got no results.

Comment: @Mark Byers: on my Samsung Spica, when the alarm fires, it logs using the tag "AlarmClock". Try filtering using "tag: AlarmClock" (assuming aLogCat uses the same filtering syntax as Eclipse's LogCat) and see again.

Comment: +1 I was also going to suggest checking logs via logcat.  Also not certain if the stock alarm will log its alerts

Comment: I can't find any (useful) logs for the alarm clock on my phone (it's the HTC Desk Clock application). I'm not sure if it's because it's not logging or because I'm doing it wrong.